# Selenium server cannot be started inside Bamboo

Tags: selenium, bamboo

I am trying to configure a Selenium testing through Bamboo. I am able to run Selenium scripts directly from command line, however it always fails if I run it through Bamboo remote agent. The error is:

```
: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:107)
```

I took some advice from the web, and checked "Allow service to interact with desktop" for Bamboo remote agent service. However, it does not work.

Anyone have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You must run Bamboo in Console Mode for this to work.  Also, the build machine desktop must be active - and not covered or minimized if you want mouse simulations to work.  I know right!